# CSS3 Oblique vs Italics a font with both?

Tags: html, css, fonts

My understanding of Oblique font styling in CSS3 is that it's the same as the normal font, with an angle applied.

Italics on the other hand, is a separate set of glyphs, that while slanted also feature unique characters, like an extra curly z, or a pronounced y, whatever.

Now, I've been running font-style: oblique, and font-style: italic, on many different fonts. One example would be http://www.google.com/fonts#QuickUsePlace:quickUse however, the situation appears to be no matter if I call Oblique, or Italic, the result looks the same. I've yet to find a font that contains both Oblique and Italic styling. In reality you seem to get one or another.

Does anyone know why this is? I would have assumed by using Oblique as a setting, it would have taken the basic font, and simply displayed it at an angle. Am I misunderstanding this?

And if Oblique and Italic just reference one set of characters, what is the point of it even being in CSS3 when it makes no practical different with all the fonts I've seen so far?

Comment: The [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-style-prop) actually says for a value of `oblique`, that if an oblique variation doesn't exist but an italic one does, then the italic should be used. I'm just as baffled why it wouldn't just default to faux oblique in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Oblique and Italic are two different styles. They don't look the same; the fact that they *seem* to look the same is caused by the program that displays the font (i.e. the browser); it shows the variant that is present, so if you specify `oblique`, it uses italic if oblique isn't available, and vice versa.

Now it's possible for a font to come with both an italic and an oblique variant, and then you can distinguish between those by using `italic` or `oblique`. However, in reality such fonts are rare. Very rare.
[Lucida Grande](http://lucidafonts.com/fonts/family/lucida-grande) is one such font. If you're willing to fork money over for it.
I also found [Kinnari](https://packages.debian.org/sid/fonts/fonts-tlwg-kinnari), a free font, which is in the Linux repositories even.
(If anyone knows about more fonts like that, I'd be delighted!)

However, if you're willing to experiment a little, you can use a font editor like [FontForge](http://fontforge.github.io/en-US/) to create slanted fonts from regular ones. So what do you do, you select a font on your machine that has an italic variant, then take the regular version, slant it with the editor and change the style to "Oblique" instead of "Regular". There, you now have a font with both oblique and italic!

Answer (score 0):

It is my opinion...

When you pick one family font, it has many forms (normal, bold, italic, ...).

Usually, if you want to display a font cursive, you should use the italic style instead oblique style, that's because it's the default form which come from in the family font that you chose.

If you use oblique style, it's like a imitation used by the browser to display that font in cursive.

Comment: I agree to a point. My issue here is, that we have two font-style settings, oblique and italic. What's the point if both simply call the default italic if there is one, or default to oblique if there isn't one. My issue here is, that no matter what you choose, font-style: italic or font-style: oblique, you get the same result.

Comment: Yes, I'm agree with you. Maybe that is for old browsers that couldn't find a font style cursive inside the family font, and it used the oblique way to make the font cursive. I hope I have clarified your doubts a little bit.

Comment: Yes thank you, I wasn't sure if I wasn't using it right somehow and thus not getting the expected result, or if it was just that CSS3 wasn't behaving in the way described. Now I know the score I'll forget about Oblique.